# How to fix this 'undefined' when i try to display the sum in the element "pro1'

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get the value from the element 'amt1' which increases everytime i onclick a button and display it on the element 'pro1'. however, i am receiving the value 'undefined' im really new to javascript. hope someone could help me. thank you in advance!

```
var add1 = function(sum) {
    return function () {
      document.getElementById("amt1").innerHTML = ++sum;
      var price1 = document.getElementById("amt1").value;
      return price1;
    };
}(0);
var total1 = price1*parseFloat(119.90);
function displayPrice(){
  document.getElementById('pro1').innerHTML = total1;
}
```

Comment: You are setting `innerHTML` of the `"amt1"` but try to access its `value`

Comment: You're also directly trying to access `price1` instead of `add1`.

Comment: Also, use parseInt of parseFloat when using the content of a non-input HTML element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`price1` is a local variable in the lexical scope of the function returned by `sum` function. It's value is not available in the outer scope when you try to multiply it by `119.90`.

You can get the price from the element `amt1` dynamically inside `displayPrice` function instead.

Also if `amt1`element is not an `input` then you should use `.textContent` property of the element instead of `.value`:

```js
var add1 = function(sum) {
    return function () {
      document.getElementById("amt1").innerHTML = ++sum;
    };
}(0);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', add1)

function displayPrice(){
  var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amt1").textContent);
  var total = price * 119.90;
  document.getElementById('pro1').innerHTML = total;
}

document.querySelectorAll('button')[1].addEventListener('click', displayPrice)
```

```html
<p id="amt1">0</p>
<button>Add</button>
<br><br>
<button>Total</button>
<p id="pro1"><p>
```

Comment: I think this only partly answers the question. The `add1` function expects a parameter so I assume it must be called in order for it to function in the first place. Could be wrong here, been a while since I've done JS like this

Comment: @icecub As I can see form the code snippet posted by the OP, add1 is invoked as IIFE with `0`

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. But doesn't that mean it'll always reset back to 0 in this case?

Comment: It depends on the context where this IIFE is evaluated. I assume it's the main module rather than an event handler, if it's so then it will reset to 0 on page reload.

Comment: @icecub My pleasure :)